# Tensorflow: How to set dtype of action_spec to float value? Error:Value for attr 'Tshape' of float is not in the list of allowed values: int32, int64

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

Im trying to set the dtype of the action_spec and observation_spec for my Custom Enviroment to a float16 or 32

i havent been able to find any similar problems to mine on here, so any help is appreciated, thanks!

ive been getting this error:

```
Value for attr 'Tshape' of float is not in the list of allowed values: int32, int64
    ; NodeDef: {{node Reshape}}; Op<name=Reshape; signature=tensor:T, shape:Tshape -> output:T; attr=T:type; attr=Tshape:type,default=DT_INT32,allowed=[DT_INT32, DT_INT64]> [Op:Reshape]

Call arguments received by layer 'CategoricalQNetwork' (type CategoricalQNetwork):
  • observation=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 1024, 2), dtype=float16)
  • step_type=tf.Tensor(shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
  • network_state=()
  • training=False
  In call to configurable 'DqnAgent' (<class 'tf_agents.agents.dqn.dqn_agent.DqnAgent'>)
  In call to configurable 'CategoricalDqnAgent' (<class 'tf_agents.agents.categorical_dqn.categorical_dqn_agent.CategoricalDqnAgent'>)
```

this is my enviroment:

```
        def __init__(self, actor: carla.libcarla.Vehicle, lidar_data):
            super().__init__()

            #want this to be flaot16
            self._action_spec = specs.BoundedArraySpec(
                shape=(), dtype=np.float16, minimum=0, maximum=1, name='action')

            #and this too
            self._observation_spec = specs.BoundedArraySpec(
                shape=(1024, 2), dtype=np.float16, minimum=0, maximum=1, name='observation')

            self._actor: carla.libcarla.Actor = actor
            self._world: carla.libcarla.World = actor.get_world()

            self._lidar_data = lidar_data

            location = self._actor.get_location()
            self._initial_location: (float, float) = (location.x, location.y)
            self._last_location: (float, float) = self._initial_location

            self._should_reset = False
            self._episode_ended = False

            self._observation = np.full((1024, 2), 0.0, dtype=np.float16)
```

this is how i have the QNetwork set up:

```
categorical_q_net = categorical_q_network.CategoricalQNetwork(
        train_env.observation_spec(),
        train_env.action_spec(),
        num_atoms=num_atoms,
        fc_layer_params=fc_layer_params)

    optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

    train_step_counter = tf.Variable(0)

    agent = categorical_dqn_agent.CategoricalDqnAgent(
        train_env.time_step_spec(),
        train_env.action_spec(),
        categorical_q_network=categorical_q_net,
        optimizer=optimizer,
        min_q_value=min_q_value,
        max_q_value=max_q_value,
        n_step_update=n_step_update,
        td_errors_loss_fn=common.element_wise_squared_loss,
        gamma=gamma,
        train_step_counter=train_step_counter)
    agent.initialize()
```

Comment: When I remember right, a `DQN` network can only work with a discrete `action space`. An `action space` with float values is not discrete anymore.